# Keep font on computer

Tags: macos, mac, font, font-book

The font Kaiti SC keeps uninstalling itself from my macbook and I need to re-download it every few days.

How can I stop it from being removed? I would like to always have this font available.

Comment: Why do you say that it is being removed?  Removed by what process?

Comment: @MarcWilson it's just, some days I will suddenly notice "oh, this text that should be rendering in Kaiti isn't... let me check fontbook... [[ this is a font that needs to be downloaded before it can be previewed ]]" and I have to download it again

Answer (score 1):

Kaiti SC is an optional font that can be downloaded from Apple using FontBook.

I can't explain why it is being 'removed' from your computer, but if you want to keep it, you need to locate it (using Show in Finder on right-click in Font Book), and copy it to `/Library/Fonts`.

Comment: 'Show in Finder' is greyed-out on this font....

Comment: Is it downloaded? It's possible that Apple have removed it from Monterey. Do you have it on a backup?

Comment: It is downloaded, and I can re-download it every time it undownloads itself

Comment: Then when it is downloaded, copy it to your Font folder.

Comment: How can I copy it to my font folder?

Comment: @theonlygusti  Look for Kaiti SC in System/Library/Fonts and drag it to your desktop so you can put it in Library/Fonts or Home/Library/Fonts.

Comment: It's not in there. But a `find /` did come across some STKaiti files deep in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`

Comment: That's why I said use the "Show in Finder". If that doesn't work, they'll be in /System/Library/AssetsV2. There are couple of folders in there with the word "Font" in them.